# Linker error when building MFC com project with Makefile of Visual studio

Tags: c++, batch-file, mfc, makefile

I'm using VC++ visual studio 2008 to debug a MFC program. when I compile it,there is the error message" fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'SOURCE\Hide..\lib\Debug\i386\libcppvc7.lib"
I have tried to fix this error, it cannot work , too. Please tell me How fix this error?

Comment: How have you tried to fix the error? This really is something that you should be able to solve.

Comment: I definitely tried to fix the error but i couldnt find it. , If u know, please tell me.

Comment: libcppvc7.lib is really in the Debug folder (at the good place) ?

Answer (score 0):

This particular issue is caused by specifying a dependency to a lib file that had spaces in its path. The path needs to be surrounded by quotes for the project to compile correctly. On the Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input tab of the project’s properties, there is an Additional Dependencies property. You need to place quotation marks as :

> "'SOURCE\Hide..\lib\Debug\i386\libcppvc7.lib"